# What is this component on a GoPro 4th generation mainboard?

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

Could someone help me identify this component? Unfortunately the GoPro was not charging, and this faulty component is likely the cause.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

thanks for the responses!

A friend who analyzed the board claims, that the marked component does not work properly. It is said, that it does not provide sufficient voltage (3,3V) for the functioning of the cooperating components. But he returned it to me saying, that he can't replace it, because the component is unmarked.

Comment: Can you post a schematic please? Where are the PCB reference designators?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here (Surface Mount Devices marked ‘SF’):

https://smd.yooneed.one/code5346.html

It’s most likely a Linear Voltage Regulator (1.5 volt).

Comment: The only device that appears to fit your list is a switch mode regulator. Did you check the number of pins in the picture?